# Android: Switch statement used with OnItemClickListener() is always choosing last case regardless of selected item

Tags: android, gallery, switch-statement

Having a hard time figuring out the best way to go about this. What I've got going on is a gallery view loaded with images, with a text view just beneath it. I would like to fill the contents of the textview based upon which image is clicked. I followed the standard GalleryView tutorial where it has you create a custom ImageAdapter class which extends the BaseAdapter class. In doing so, I created an OnItemClickListener for the galleryview, and I assumed the next logical step would be to create a switch statement to figure out what to put in the text view.

So I eventually figured out that I should probably be itererating over the gallery items as opposed to the parameters passed to the onitemclicklistener() method. The problem is now, no matter what item is clicked, the output to the desired text view is always as if the last item was clicked. I commented out the 'case 2', and it then began to always take case 1. What would be causing the switch statement to 'default' to the last case coded even though I have not defined a default case?

Additionally, I'm seeing conflicting stuff regarding the switch statement in terms of looping. It should loop on its own, yes? If so I imagine it probably is, but since it always selects case 2, I'm not realizing that the output of the text should be changing? Is my switch statement all messed up? do I need to include some sort of loop? What am I doing wrong here?

Custom ImageAdapter class:

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        context = c;
        //---setting the style---
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
         R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();                    
        }
 //---returns the number of images---
 public int getCount() {
     return imageIDs.length;
 }
 //---returns the ID of an item--- 
 public Object getItem(int position) {
     return position;
 }            

 public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 //---returns an ImageView view---
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
     imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
     imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
     return imageView;
 }
}
}
```

And here is the code I'm using to create the galleryview and the onitemclicklistener:

```
Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.top_gallery);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
                View v, int position, long id) 
                {
                    TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cat_desc);
                    switch(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition())
                    {   
                    case 0:
                        tView.setText("Option1");

                    case 1:
                        tView.setText("Option2");

                    case 2:
                        tView.setText("Option3");
}
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're lacking break's in case statement and code gets executed in linear way. That's why the last is always selected.

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason I was interpreting the the break as stopping the entire loop all together, not just the switch statement. I forgot the onclick listener would keep listening regardless.

Answer (score 1):

You need break; in your case, else it will fall through. Try:

```
case 0 : tView.setText("Option1"); break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `breaks;`

```
switch(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition())
{   
    case 0:
        tView.setText("Option1");
        break;
    case 1:
        tView.setText("Option2");
        break;
     case 2:
        tView.setText("Option3");
        break;
}
```